# is there a libboost-all instead of libboost-all-dev?

Tags: libraries

I need `libboost` dependency for a package I'm running, but the only package I can find is  `libboost-all-dev`, and I'm not sure what the "dev" means and if I need it. Is there a `libboost-all-<Something>` that I need to install instead?

Answer (score 3):

The `boost-all-dev` contains files used for building software that uses Boost. The Boost shared libraries themselves are split into multiple packages (`libboost-chrono*`, `libboost-date-time*`, `libboost-graph*`, etc.).